# Do you know any real-world, useful WPF/Silverlight applications using MVVM?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, mvvm

I'm looking for code of full applications that **(1) use the MVVM pattern** and **(2) are approachable for WPF/Silverlight/MVVM beginners**. So far I have only found:

- [Crack.NET](http://www.codeplex.com/cracknetproject/SourceControl/ListDownloadableCommits.aspx) - A runtime debugging and scripting tool (useful but quite complicated)
- [CipherText](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ExploringWPFMVVM.aspx) - WPF Password Manager (perfect but written in VB.NET)

What are some others?

*preferably smaller helper apps or tools that use MVVM but that have a completed feel, perhaps with WPF/Silverlight graphic/animation goodness, etc. which show not only the MVVM concepts being used but in a context of a real-world, completed application*

## My Contribution

Thanks for all the tips, I collected together a list of 15+ MVVM code examples and posted the here:

**[Overview of WPF/Silverlight code examples that help you learn MVVM](http://tanguay.info/web/index.php?pg=notesItems&id=28)**.

Comment: I think the dearth of answers to this question really says something about MVVM... over hyped, but little in the way of demonstrable success? P.S. If you look at Blend (the originator of MVVM) you will find little the resembles MVVM as touted by most proponents...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the question, you may be interested in the current effort going on to create a "Pet Shop" type reference implementation for M-V-VM.  You can join the conversation or follow progress [here](http://www.codeplex.com/mvvmref).

Answer (score 4):

I too class myself as a beginner in MVVM developing a large scale application for about a month now. I'm over most of the main hurdles, but keep getting confused up by a few things.

Be careful with the suggestions from Kent. They'll get you started, but the subtle differences in Silverlight and WPF will trip you up occasionally (triggers are one).

I don't know of any full sites, but I started with the Composite Application Guidance and  PRISM libraries. These a little too cumbersome for a 'beginner' and just MVVM, but some of the concepts are very useful (event aggregator for example).

I suggest that you read blogs by Josh Twist, Josh Smith, Shaun Wildermuth and Nikhil Kothari. These guys are very knowledgeable. They are also very open to answering questions too.

What is your development background? Some of the concepts surrounding method calls, responses and delegation are a real break from "traditional sequential" coding techniques.

Comment: thanks for the name tips, my background is mainly stateless web programming, never did e.g. C++ or winforms, so the whole stateful/delegate/event model + .NET 3.5 + XAML/Binding/Commands/Routing/triggers/etc + MVP/MVVM patterns are new concepts, determined to plow through them though, real apps help

Comment: I came from ASP.NET back ground too and found the Asynchrounous progeramming model the hardest to grasp. Having to raise and subscribe to events seemed like oodles of extra code at the start, but after a month or two it make perfect sense, and helps isolate components nicely. Updates are now simple.

Answer (score 2):

Try [this one](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2009/04/02/mvvm-mediator-acb-cool-wpf-app-intro/). Also, [Family.Show](http://www.codeplex.com/familyshow) may be useful.

Comment: Family.Show was started when WPF was still Avalon and we didn't use the MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using MVVM for the last couple of months on a project and it's been fantastic. I've been doing UI work for over 12 years and it's the best thing I've come across.

Comment: I agree. MVVM is a smart pattern indeed, and make updates to code so easy.

Comment: most of the hour-long MVVM examples that I am working through I could do without MVVM in about 5 minutes with simple code behind, such as this prism example, 20+ classes just to get master/detail working, when do the benefits start to kick in? http://tanguay.info/web/index.php?pg=codeExamples&id=105

Comment: You probably would not see the benefits in doing an hour long example for MVVM. Of course you could knock together a quick demonstration quicker - but that is not what this pattern is about. The benefits kick in when using on larger projects, where the UI is seperate from the business logic.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using MVVM for about 2 years now, and I can say that it is a resounding success.  I have shipped one large-scale medical imaging solution using MVVM in Silverlight.  I am also about to ship a complicated WPF application using Prism and MVVM extensively.  In fact, I don't know how I'd achieve some of my problems elegantly without MVVM in this more recent application.

+1 on MVVM.  It works.  It is testable.  It is extensible.  It facilitates developer-designer workflows. It ALSO doesn't have to be messy and plumbing-heavy.

In addition, I created a medium-sized Silverlight application using MVVM for the CodeMash conference in January.  You can see it and get the [source code here](http://houseofbilz.com/archives/2010/01/11/adventures-in-mvvm-codemash-schedule-application/).

Answer (score 1):

The [WPF Disciples group](http://groups.google.co.za/group/wpf-disciples/browse_thread/thread/d94b282e8d5bd245/f9ef408a309f8392?show_docid=f9ef408a309f8392) has decided to create a real-world MVVM + Mediator reference application similar to the Pet Shop refence application for Web Apps. Your can follow the development on codeplex [here](http://www.codeplex.com/mvvmref)